# Failed to create Dockerfile image /bin/sh: apt-get: not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

HI can I ask some help I'm building the image Dockerfile
but I get this error `/bin/sh: apt-get: not found` , I did not pull O.S because I know docker has a default O.S ?

```
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r9.trigger
OK: 12 MiB in 31 packages
Removing intermediate container 9a28ea5578ed
 ---> 73b493dcd606
Step 3/7 : RUN apt-get update    &&  apt-get install –y nginx
 ---> Running in 9e2bb52cd7c8
/bin/sh: apt-get: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update    &&  apt-get install –y nginx' returned a non-zero code: 127




FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
#RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN apt-get update \
   &&  apt-get install –y nginx

COPY index.php /var/www/myapp
ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you are using `alpine` base image not `ubuntu`. So, the package manager for `alpine` is `apk` not `apt` or `apt-get`

Command should be

```
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache nginx
```

`--no-cache` option allows to not cache the index locally, which is useful for keeping containers small.

> Ref:- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/10-alpine-linux-apk-command-examples/

Comment: what does --no-cache  do ?

Comment: The `--no-cache` option allows to not cache the index locally, which is useful for keeping containers small.

Answer (score 4):

The Linux distribution for your base image `php:7.4-fpm-alpine` is [Alpine](https://alpinelinux.org/) instead of Ubuntu, so you need to use [`apk`](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management) instead of `apt-get` as package manager.

```
RUN apk update && apk add nginx
```